# set boot drive manually

Tags: hard-drive, multi-boot

I would like to specify the bootdrive of my computer manually (using a switch or microcontroller), because I have currently 3 hard drives in my computer: a Data drive, a hdd with mac osx and a hdd with windows os. I am trying to use a switch and microcontroller to select the bootdrive, so that I don't have to use a bootloader. This means that the windows boots, together with the data drive, or the mac osx boots with the data drive. Is there a way to do this (i.e. jumpers)?

Comment: Are your drives SATA or IDE?

Comment: all drives are SATA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you have a motherboard with at least two SATA hard drive connectors
>   and have at least two SATA drives, you can build a low-cost physical
>   switch to select multiple operating systems.

[Example](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/82086-build-your-own-sata-hard-drive-switch)

But some people [recommend you buy a commercial product](http://www.pcworld.com/article/160260/how_to_make_your_own_exploding_sata_switch.html)

[image: SATA switch]

Comment: Thank you for the good information, for the moment I already use the switch (using the same technique from the extreme tech article), but that is without a 3th data drive. When I want to use a data drive to, the problem is that that drive spins up before the drive with the os does. This results in a bootsequence with the data drive at the first place and then the os hdd. When I want to solve this issue, I think I will have to go with the commercial product?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would highly recommend using a bootloader. Why not?

Otherwise, if we're talking about SATA (or even adapted to IDE), [this guide](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/82086-build-your-own-sata-hard-drive-switch) will show you how to build your own SATA switch by disabling power to one of the drives.

Comment: I would like to not use a bootloader because this is part of a remote booting mechanism. Since I want to be able to start both operating systems remotely, I can als not use the default selection for that.